# Time Dilation Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation

[image: Here's the formula...]

I'm having some trouble using the time dilation formula. Say an astronaut leaves Earth for 10 years, at 0.85c. How much time has passed according to an observer on Earth?

I tried using the following formula:

$$t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v^2/c^2)}}$$

but couldn't seem to get an answer that made sense.

Any help would be much appreciated! This concept is super confusing to me.

Comment: I think you might be missing a term in your formula.

Comment: Leaves for 10 years in what frame?

Comment: Okay. I wrote the formula exactly how it appeared on my formula sheet, but it's possible I'm missing something. Any idea what term?

Comment: Leaves for 10 years relative to the astronaut

Comment: Your image equation is a little different from the formula you typed, do you see what is missing?

Comment: Sorry the equation I wrote has a typo, my mistake. I do see what is missing, for some reason the formula was written with 1 somewhere else. Sorry!

Comment: Okay, so if I substitute the rest time (10 years) in for t, do I have to covert 10 years to seconds, since my velocity is in m/s?

Comment: No need to convert time units - the only thing that might require speed in m/s is the calculation of $\gamma$ (the thing in the denominator) - and since $v$ is expressed as a fraction of $c$, you can just simplify that to $\sqrt{1-0.85^2}$. After that it doesn't matter what units you use for time.

Comment: I hope that the original homework question was much more precisely expressed.  You need to ask a question relating to the differences between clocks that are compared when they are brought back together.  Clocks that are separated cannot be compared (unless they are at rest relative to one another, in which case a comparison procedure can be defined).  Think clocks and rulers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your written text says "t = 1/sqrt[1-(v^2/c^2)]".  If you used that equation, it's no wonder you got a nonsensical value.  In the equation in the scanned image, that's a letter $t$ in the numerator, not the digit $1$.

Also, although it works for this problem, the scanned image should really say something like

$$\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\ .$$

As it's written, it looks like it's expressing a coordinate transformation between the two frames instead of just expressing the time dilation factor, and interpreted as a coordinate transformation the equation would in general be wrong.  The general coordinate transformation for the standard configuration is

$$t' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \left( t - \frac{vx}{c^2} \right)\ .$$

That equation reduces to the scanned equation if you're only dealing with the world line $x=0$.  $x=0$ in this problem expresses that the astronaut is standing still in his coordinate system.